# I can't get a pound sign (£) to print to the screen

Tags: java

If I write

```
System.out.println("\u00A3");
System.out.println("\u0024");
```

it outputs:

```
ú
$
```

am I doing something wrong? Is it something to do with command prompt? the dollar sign is displaying correctly...but not the pound sign

any and all help appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: What operating system are you using? Windows?

Comment: Windows prompt is incapable of showing many unicode characters. Try changing prompt's fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the encoding being used in the command prompt terminal using the `chcp` command. If this produces for example

```
Active code page: 850
```

then the encoding corresponds to the charset `IBM850`. Then you can use

```
java -Dfile.encoding=IBM850 MyApplication
```

which will produce the correct output

Comment: it did indeed produce code page: 850
but I don't know how to do what you said after, I'm very new to Java...:/

Comment: well how do you run your application?

Comment: using javac and then java

Comment: then use the java command above to run your application or course replacing the `MyApplication` bit with your class name...

Comment: If it isn't 850, then how do you determine the correct `file.encoding` value?  Is there a chart somewhere?  Mine said 437, and it turned out IBM437 worked, but I'm sure that isn't true for every possibility.

Comment: ohh sorry I see what you're saying, I hadn't understood what was written. That works, thanks :)

Comment: @Daemon OK, that would tell me which code pages are identified as IBM.  But it doesn't spell out what the correct parameter value would be for Java (especially if the code page isn't an IBM one).

Comment: @ajb True, but most of the time you'll be using the file.encoding system property with UTF-8 (Unicode) unless you encounter a "special" case as seen here. AFAIK, there is no comprehensive list of code page param values for the file.encoding property.

Comment: @ajb Looks like I was mistaken, here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

Answer (score 0):

Your current `Locale` may change the symbols you get.  Try using `getSymbol()` from the [Currency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html) class.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm pretty new to Java I don't know what you're suggesting :/